# How do I Iterate through every item on a list, manipulate each item without a limit and that the list is user inputted? Python

Tags: python

im new to python and I can't properly explain it, but like, im trying to make a pyglatin translator but instead of just words It can accept sentences, yes I have seen the other ways to do this but Im attempting to do it in a different way for practice.

How do I make it manipulate each item infinitely til it runs out of items to modify and then break the loop after? I'll appreciate any help, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object that is a list, you can use a `for` loop to loop through them.

```py
a = ['item 1','item 2'] # the square brackets denote a list
for item in a:
    print(item)
print('done with the list')
```

This code will print 'item 1' and then 'item 2', ending the list. When it gets to the end of the list, it will automatically exit the loop and print 'done with the list'. The commands within the loop as designated by the indentation. That is, I could have a second line of code with the same indentation that would also be in the loop.

So you make your code in the loop do whatever it needs to do. Maybe it makes a new list with your updates and uses `.append()` to add those new items to it, the world is yours.

You can get input from a user at the command prompt using `x = input('This will display'`. You save whatever they input as a string to the variable `x`. If it is a sentence, `x` will be a string that is that sentence. If you want a list with the individual words, you can do `x.split()` to return a list made up of each individual word.